# MarkLogic 10 document format change when editing with Query Console

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

After doing the upgrade to MarkLogic 10, we are seeing a issue with Query console where document format is getting changed if we edit it from QC.

Steps to recreate :-

Step 1 :- Insert a small XML doc using QC

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := 
<Football>
<Team><ManchesterUnited> United finished 2nd in PL </ManchesterUnited></Team>
</Football>
for $i in 1 to 5
return xdmp:document-insert ('/England/PL/ManchesterUnited/'||$i||'', $doc)
```

Step 2 :- Check One Document format like below

```
let $x:= doc("/England/PL/ManchesterUnited/1")/node()
return
typeswitch ( $x )
 case element() return "xml element node"
 case text() return "text node"
 case binary() return "binary node"
default return "don't know"
```

Output will be "xml element node"

Step 3:- Edit the document from query console click "Edit", and change element value.

for ex

```
<ManchesterUnited> United finished 2nd in PL </ManchesterUnited>
```

to

```
<ManchesterUnited> Manchester United are the new champions </ManchesterUnited>
```

Step 4 :- Run the step 2 again and now the format of document is changed to "text node".

Any Suggestion on how we can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Query Console in which documents that do not have a file extension in the URI are being saved as `text()`. It will be addressed in future MarkLogic releases.

For now, avoid using the Query Console edit feature for documents who's URIs do not have a file extension, or consider applying ".xml" suffix for such XML documents.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Please let us know the version of ML in which it is fixed.

Comment: BUG-56551 was addressed in MarkLogic 10.0-7.1, which is available for download now.